# Composite index link is not Generated in Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently using Firestore version 24.10.0 in my Android app. The problem I'm facing is that when I send queries, there is no response, and the composite indexing link doesn't get generated. There are no crashes occurring. I've noticed that this issue has recurred several times over the past three years, and unfortunately, it's happening again now.

Comment: Can you try to use the developer console to create the index directly?

Comment: What is the exact query that you're performing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Firestore developer console to directly create indexes based on collections and fields.

**Firebase Console > Firestore > Indexes > Create Index**

[image]

Comment: I already did that but still have no response for any new query structure.

Comment: Is the query returning no results or is it returning nothing at all? Are you sure the query you've created is correct?